# How to add (or subtract) a value by pressing the submit button PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have the following code=>

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="first" name="geri" type="submit" value="<?php ?>">BACK</button>   
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="second" name="ileri" type="submit" value="<?php ?>">FORWARD</button>
```

These buttons submit the form to the same page. At the top of the page I have variable $t which is initialized at value '0' and is followed by the codes=>

```
     $t=0;


if( $this->input->post('ileri') ) { $t=$t+1;} // Back  button was pressed; 
if( $this->input->post('geri') ) { $t=$t-1;} // Forward button was pressed;
```

Now as I press forward I want to increase $t and when I press back I want to decrease it. But because of the declaration at the top ($t=0;) it goes as far as '1' with 'forward' and as back as '0' with 'back' buttons. Can anyone think of a way of getting over this problem.
Thank you...

Comment: lots of way. learn more about get,post, session,cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hidden input, and store *$t* there. This gets posted upon submit:

```
<?php
$t = $this->input->post('t');
if (!$t) $t = 0;
if( $this->input->post('ileri') ) { $t=$t+1;} // Back  button was pressed; 
if( $this->input->post('geri') ) { $t=$t-1;} // Forward button was pressed;
?>
<input name="t" type="hidden" value="<?=$t ?>"> 
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="first" name="geri" type="submit" value="submit">BACK</button>   
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="second" name="ileri" type="submit" value="submit">FORWARD</button>
```

Comment: Hello $trincot. This sound good but how do we set up the initial value of $t? echo 0;  or echo $t=0; did not work....That is inside the t input... Regards

Comment: Updated my answer to perform initialisation of $t when no submission took place.

Comment: Hello @trincot ! Perfect!! One thing though ... You have omitted my code which went ....value="<?php ?>" . It did not work without the form system submitting a value. Thank you again for taking your time with my query and best regards....

Comment: I see. Added the value attribute again, but just with a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use url parameter. Get instead of post. so that it stores the current value of variable $t i.e.

```
if (isset($_GET['t']))

{
 $t = $_GET['t'];
}
else
{
$t = 0;
}
```

Something like that could be of some help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what button makes the submit you need to change the buttons

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="first" name="geri" type="submit" value="<?php ?>">BACK</button>   
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="second" name="ileri" type="submit" value="<?php ?>">FORWARD</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="first" name="s_button" type="submit" value="geri">BACK</button>   
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning text-center but-width" id="second" name="s_button" type="submit" value="ileri">FORWARD</button>
```

in your controller

```
$button_s = $this->input->post('s_button');

if( isset($button_s)){
    switch($button_s){
        case 'geri':
                    //do somthing
                    break;
        case 'ileri':
                    //do somthing
                    break;
    }
}
```